# Count the number of integer solutions to $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_5=36$

Tags: combinatorics, diophantine-equations, integer-partitions

How to count the number of integer solutions to  $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_5=36$ such that $x_1\ge 4,x_3 = 11,x_4\ge 7$

And how about $x_1\ge 4, x_3=11,x_4\ge 7,x_5\le 5$

In both cases, $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ must be nonnegative integers.

Is there a general formula to calculate things like this?

Comment: I think that if you re-write the question as Maximize: x1+x2+x3+x4+x5-36 where $x_i$ > 0 and $x_1\ge 4, x_3=11,x_4\ge 7,x_5\le 5$, you could use the linear programming method called Simplex method to find values of $x_i$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose you had no constraints on the $x_i$. Your problem is addressed by the "[Stars and Bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)" method (or, if you do not wish to count the order of your summands, the [Partition Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_%28number_theory%29#Partition_function)).

Now, your first question can be reduced to the question with no constraints by asking:

What is the number of non-negative integer solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_4 + x_5 = 14$?

What I did was set $x_3 = 11$ and subtract 11 from the righthand side and remove $x_3$ from consideration, since we may as well regard $x_3$ as a constant.

For $x_1$ and $x_4$, subtract 4 and 7, respectively, from the righthand side. Now we care only that $x_1 \geq 0$ and $x_4 \geq 0$. In other words, we want the number of non-negative integer solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_4 + x_5 = 14$.

To take care of a constraint like $x_5 \leq 5$, first find the number of solutions with no constraints on $x_5$. Then, find the number of solutions with $x_5 \geq 6$. Subtract the latter from the former.

Answer (score 3):

In all your case, essentially we want to find the number of natural number solutions for the following equation:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i = N$$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{N}$

The method is as follows:

Consider $N$ sticks.

$| | | | | | | | ... | | |$

We want to do partition these $N$ sticks into $n$ parts.

This can be done if we draw $n-1$ long vertical lines in between these $N$ sticks.

The number of gaps between these $N$ sticks is $N-1$.

So the total number of ways of drawing these $n-1$ long vertical lines in between these $N$ sticks is $C(N-1,n-1)$.

So the number of natural number solutions for $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i = N$ is $C(N-1,n-1)$.

If we are interested in the number of non-negative integer solutions, all we need to do is replace $a_i = b_i - 1$ and count the number of natural number solutions for the resulting equation in $b_i$'s.

i.e. $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} (b_i - 1) = N$ i.e. $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i = N + n$.

So the number of non-negative integer solutions to $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i = N$ is given by $C(N+n-1,n-1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach to understanding your problem in greater generality.

Suppose we would like to count the number of *non-negative* and *ordered* integer solutions of the Diophantine equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 36$ with the following additional constraints: $x_1 \geq 4$, $x_3 = 11$ and $x_4 \geq 7$. First, as my colleague Mike suggests, let's subtract $x_3$ from both sides. We are then to count: $x_1 + x_2 + x_4 + x_5 = 25$ given said constraints.

I prefer to think about this problem combinatorially in terms of lattice points of dilated polytopes. The unconstrained inequality $x_1 + x_2 + x_4 + x_5 \leq R$ represents the number of non-negative lattice points of the $R$-dilate of the polytope $\mathbf{conv}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{e}_1, \mathbf{e}_2, \mathbf{e}_3, \mathbf{e}_4)$, which is bounded by a $4$-simplex or [pentachoron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentachoron) and the natural boundaries of the positive orthant, where $\mathbf{e}_i$ represents the $i^{\text{th}}$ basis of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$. For simplicity, we'll just call this object a *simplicial $4$-polytope* $P$.

It is clear that the number non-negative solutions of $x_1 + x_2 + x_4 + x_5 = R$ is found by considering the inequality $R - 1 < x_1 + x_2 + x_4 + x_5 \leq R$ which can be determined by simply subtracting the number of lattice points of two consecutive dilates of the same pentachoron. That said, the number of non-negative lattice points of an $R$-dilate of $P$ is the iterated sum,
\begin{align}
N(R) = \sum_{i_1 = 0}^{R} \sum_{i_2 = 0}^{R - i_1} \sum_{i_3 = 0}^{R - i_1 -i_2} \sum_{i_4 = 0}^{R - i_1 -i_2 -i_3} 1 = \binom{R + 4}{R}.
\end{align}
So, with no constraints, we have the following number of non-negative solutions:
\begin{align}
\binom{R+4}{R} - \binom{R + 3}{R - 1}.
\end{align}
To account for the constraints, we modify the various limits of summation accordingly,
\begin{align}
N(R) = \sum_{i_1 = 4}^{R} \sum_{i_2 = 0}^{R - i_1} \sum_{i_3 = 7}^{R - i_1 -i_2} \sum_{i_4 = 0}^{ R-i_1 - i_2 - i_3} 1.
\end{align}
So the answer to your first question (without a constraint on $x_5$) is therefore $N(25) - N(24)$, which is $680$. To account for the constraint on $x_5$, we further modify the innermost summation,
\begin{align}
N(R) = \sum_{i_1 = 4}^{R} \sum_{i_2 = 0}^{R - i_1} \sum_{i_3 = 7}^{R - i_1 -i_2} \sum_{i_4 = 0}^{ \min(5, R-i_1 - i_2 - i_3)} 1.
\end{align}
The answer to your second question is therefore $N(25) - N(24)$, which is $515$.

To compute the solutions explicitly, use the following mathematica code:

FindInstance[x1 + x2 + x4 + x5 == 25 && x1 >= 4 && x2 >= 0 && x4 >= 7 && x5 >= 0, {x1, x2, x4, x5}, Integers, 1000]}

FindInstance[x1 + x2 + x4 + x5 == 25 && x1 >= 4 && x2 >= 0 && x4 >= 7 && 5 >= x5 >= 0, {x1, x2, x4, x5}, Integers, 1000]}

Compute the "Length[]" of the output and you can verify that there are indeed $680$ and $515$ integral solutions, respectively.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the mathematica code!

Answer (score 1):

First things first.  Let's take $x_3$ out of the equation, leaving us with $x_1+x_2+x_4+x_5=25$.  For the first problem, I'm going to assume $x_2$  and $x_5$ are non-negative, otherwise, I think we're going to have infinite solutions.  We know $x_1$ is at least 4 and $x_4$ is at least 7, so that gives us a total of 14 to distribute to the 4 different variables.

To represent the distribution of these 14 items, let's use a string of 0's and 1's.  So for example, 00010001000100000 represents $x_1=4+3=7,x_2=3,x_4=7+3=10$, and $x_5=5$.  The 1's are dividers.  So we have 14 0's for the 14 items and 3 dividers.  So we have a string of size 17 and we want to set 3 of the characters to 1.  The number of such strings is $\binom {17}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\infty$, if you have no constraint on $x_2$ and $x_5$ other than that they are integers:  note that you can always add $1$ to one of these and subtract $1$ from the other.  Or did you mean nonnegative (or positive) integers?